# Kubernetes Rest API node CPU and RAM usage in percentage

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-metrics

I would like to develop a simple webservice, which returns kubernetes metrics like node / pod CPU and RAM usage in percentage.
In CLI there are commands like `kubectl top node` or `kubectl describe node` with all the metrics i need. However i am unable find such metrics in kubernetes REST api endpoints. The closest one i got is `/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes` endpoint, which shows CPU and RAM usage but no in percentage.

Is there such an endpoint which show the same information as in `top` or `describe` commands or, perhaps, there are better way than `metrics.k8s.io` addon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you issue `kubectl top node`, kubectl makes multiple HTTP requests to multiple endpoints. You can see exact endpoints by adding `--v=9` flag to `kubectl`.

For example, in my case

```text
kubectl top node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-99238d56-bv6z --v=9
[...]
I0726 10:41:18.347144    1986 round_trippers.go:435] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/cb303e6" 'https://<ip-address>/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-99238d56-bv6z'
I0726 10:41:18.489068    1986 round_trippers.go:435] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/cb303e6" 'https://<ip-address>/api/v1/nodes/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-99238d56-bv6z'
[...]
```

*(there are a lot more, those two are important to answer your question)*

First request return

```json
{
    "kind":"NodeMetrics",
    "apiVersion":"metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "metadata":{
        "name":"gke-cluster-1-default-pool-99238d56-bv6z",
        "selfLink":"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-99238d56-bv6z",
        "creationTimestamp":"2021-07-26T08:41:19Z"
    },
    "timestamp":"2021-07-26T08:41:07Z",
    "window":"30s",
    "usage":{
        "cpu":"86855567n",
        "memory":"950228Ki"
    }
}
```

`.usage.cpu` and `.usage.memory` show used CPU and memory respectively.

Second request return (truncated, the response is huge)

```json
{
    "status":{
        "capacity":{
            "attachable-volumes-gce-pd":"15",
            "cpu":"2",
            "ephemeral-storage":"98868448Ki",
            "hugepages-1Gi":"0",
            "hugepages-2Mi":"0",
            "memory":"4031624Ki",
            "pods":"110"
        },
        "allocatable":{
            "attachable-volumes-gce-pd":"15",
            "cpu":"940m",
            "ephemeral-storage":"47093746742",
            "hugepages-1Gi":"0",
            "hugepages-2Mi":"0",
            "memory":"2885768Ki",
            "pods":"110"
        }
    }
}
```

`.status.allocatable.cpu` and `.status.allocatable.memory` show how much CPU and memory can be allocated to running pods.

---

As you can see, there is no endpoint that return usage in percentage, kubectl does the calculation on the fly, to output the result in human friendly format

```text
$ kubectl top node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-99238d56-bv6z
NAME                                       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-99238d56-bv6z   108m         11%    928Mi           32%
```

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you to use official Kubernetes Client library. There you can achieve all features which are available on kubectl.
***you can achieve kubectl top command using [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/top.js) code snippet***